# Topology definition of a family of complete metrics

Tags: general-topology

Does ayone know the definition of topology generated by a family of complete metrics ? I have tried to look in the bibliography for some definition but I found nowhere. Is it just the union of the topologies given by each one of the metrics ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you mean, I think that you refer to [locally convex topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space?wprov=sfti1) and the way to define those from seminorms. See the specific paragraph in the referred Wikipedia article.